# Python: Make dictionary with folder names as key and file names as values

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to make a dictionary with folder names as key and file names as values
for different files in different folders. Below is my code to achieve that, but I am not getting the expected output.

I have a directory within that different folders are present. The directory name is `sreekanth`, within are many folders like `A`, `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, which contain `.csv` files.
I am trying to collect all the `.csv` files from the different folders and assigning them to the corresponding folder in a Python dictionary.

```python
from os.path import os
import fnmatch

d={}

l = []
file_list = []
file_list1 = []

for path,dirs,files in os.walk('/Users/amabbu/Desktop/sreekanth'):
    for f in fnmatch.filter(files,'*.csv'):
        if os.path.basename(path) in d.keys():
            file_list.append(f)
            d = {os.path.basename(path):list(file_list)}

            print("First",d)
        else:
            d.setdefault(os.path.basename(path),f)
        print("Second",d)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is a simpler way to do what you want using `defaultdict` module:

```
import os
import fnmatch
from collections import defaultdict


d=defaultdict(set)
for path,dirs,files in os.walk('/Users/amabbu/Desktop/sreekanth'):
   for f in fnmatch.filter(files,'*.csv'):
      d[os.path.basename(path)].add(f)

print(dict(d))
```

Comment: Thank you this code is working after minor chages from my side as per my expectations